# How to remove the time in report viewer

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I`m using **datetimepicker** control in my system and the format is **short**. My problem is whenever I insert a data in database and see it in a microsoft report viewer the time is showing **(12:00:00 AM)**. I want to ask how to remove that time in report?

btw im using visual studio 2008 and mc access[image: here]

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252080(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change that `TextBox` properties on `reportviewer` in design time.

<kbd>Right Click</kbd> → <kbd>Properties</kbd> → <kbd>Number</kbd> → Date